# RealProxy issues with compile time

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a class `MyProxy` derived from `RealProxy` and implemented the bare minimum of Invoke to silence compile time errors. I inherit from `MyProxy` a custom class `TabControl2` which itself wraps (ie: `decorator`) an `TabControl`.

I wish to call/intercept TabControl methods via the decorator - implementing everything myself as a learning exercize.

I understood the `Invoke()` of `RealProxy` would allow runtime interception of undefined methods in the decorator and call `Invoke()` with details of the invocation, such as method and arguments; thus allowing me to optionally invoke the original "decorated" object

I have googled for examples found many in C# and ported much of the code over to vb.

This particular bit of code is killing me:

```
Dim tabCtrlGeneric As TabControl = New TabControl()
Dim tabCtrlDecorator As TabControl = CType(New TabControlReorder(tabCtrlGeneric), TabControl)
```

Is giving me a compile time errors about type...not sure why?